# The Campaign ID submitted from the Lead Capture Page has been deleted

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to set up a Salesforce Web to Lead form via WordPress using Gravity Forms Salesforce Add-on. I have set up the Salesforce Org ID and created a feed. However, when I’m trying to test a form and have successfully submitted it. It sends an email notification saying that “The Campaign ID submitted from the Lead Capture Page has been deleted”.

Here is the sample email:

```
Subject: Salesforce Could Not Create This Lead

Salesforce could not create this lead because of the reason listed below. For more information about this error or help with Web-to-Case-Lead, please contact Customer Support.

Reason: The Campaign ID submitted from the Lead Capture Page has been deleted.
Lead Capture Page: https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8

Record Information:

Campaign_ID = My Campaign ID

city = Kwun Tong

country = Hong Kong

debug = 0

description = This is a test message

email = my personal email

encoding = UTF-8

encoding = UTF-8

first_name = Test

last_name = Testing

member_status = Sent

message = This is a test message

oid = My Campaign ID

phone = phone number

retURL = /become-a-distributorreseller/

state = Hong Kong

street = address

zip = zipcode

To incorporate this lead into salesforce.com you can key in the data above.
```

Can anyone advise what might be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Campaign ID is not a required field when submitting a Web-to-Lead form. There is one glaring error in the above that may be due to your changing the data:

m

```
essage = This is a test message

**oid = My Campaign ID**

phone = phone number
```

This should be your Org ID number. Once the Org is known the Campaign ID should be passed through and associated. Try it again after updating this field in Wordpress.